# How do I save the settings on a Ubuntu Live USB?

Tags: live-usb

I made a bootable USB pendrive which works just like a live CD. When I use it and make changes, for example, install an application, it does not save the changes I make on next reboot. Is it possible to do something about this?

**UPDATE:** I have followed the instructions in kingmilo's comment. Eventually, I ended up using "startup disk creater". Which is a great application. I decided to give 2.6 G as storage....but I faced the following problem:
[image]

Basically, I start up with the "Try Ubuntu" options...and everything gets saved (applications, wallpaper, music), but I need the extra space to work. How can I make it work in the easiest way?

**UPDATE2** it is working now with kingmilo's help/comment and some other info on properly partitioning and formatting pendrives.

Comment: What is the size of the usb? Are you planning to use this for a long time and on multiple computers?. There are several ways to do this, lets just find what suits best your needs and then explain it.

Comment: It's a 4 G pendrive...but I am thinking of getting an 8 or 16 G pendrive. I dont really wanna use it...I need it for trying things out, or something for fixing the laptops of my friends. That's why I need certain applications to be on it. I dont wannna plug it in and install, for instance, gparted all the time I am about to fix a laptop. By the way, thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: It looks like you need to unmount the drive, (don't remove though), in order to continue with Disk Creator. You cannot modify the drive while it is mounted, but it obviously needs to be plugged in. Use the Disk Utility to unmount or right-click in Unity and select Unmount.

Comment: I'll update the post...that was the issue. I had to make 2 partitions on on the pendrive and the with the disk utility formate them properly. Can you also tell me what size of a partition shall I use for all the updates and my few extra applicatons? 2 G is already occupied to max. :)

Comment: Glad it worked. The size of the partition all depends on what sort of applications and information you plan to install, I would recommend making it as big as you can taking into consideration the sizes of the relevant OS partitions. 8GB is a nice size in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, however, not with your current install of Ubuntu on your USB, you will need to reinstall it and follow the tutorial on this page:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LiveUsbPendrivePersistent

and for more information have a look here:

https://superuser.com/questions/174315/how-to-save-settings-on-bootable-usb-drive

Comment: King, that's just fine. I reinstall it then. I'll look into that link, the persistent pendrive one. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great. It's a nifty thing to have. You basically carry your PC around with you in your pocket and almost any PC becomes a host for you, really fun.

Comment: king, can you have a look at the "update" of my post? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I always use the [Universal USB Installer from pendrivelinux](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) to do my persistent bootable USB drives. Works like a champ and is regularly updated with new distros. Of course, I use a Windows box to create them and if you don't have access to one of these, unfortunately this isn't the solution for you.

Comment: what's a windows box Mat?

Comment: I'm sorry, Windows machine. :)